# Get the maximum value from a response array in karate

Tags: karate

I am trying to test an endpoint whose response is an array of days containing temparature from last 5 days and I want to know say the hottest day or the coldest day in Karate.

Here is the snippet from my feature file:

```
      * def GetDates = Java.type('com.CurveTest.GetDates')  
        * def setup = GetDates.initialSetup()
        * def ToDate = GetDates.getTodaysDate()
        * def StartDate = GetDates.get5DaysAgoDate()


   Scenario: Get the hottest day of the week in London

    Given url weather_5day_api
    And param key = apiKey
    And param q = 'london'
    And param dt = StartDate
    And param end_dt = ToDate
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And def result = response
```

In the response, the following path captures the date:

```
   forecast.forecastday[0].day.date
```

And the following path captures the max temp and min temp:

```
   forecast.forecastday[0].day.maxtemp_c
   forecast.forecastday[0].day.mintemp_c
```

My end date is today and start date is 5 days back. That means the array size is 5.

What is the best way to know which is the hottest day in the last 5 days? So I need to capture the date and maxtemp_c from the response(5 times for last 5 days) and compare the values and use the max value of temparate and use that date of the hottest day in another end point as a parameter.

I looked at the following example but did not figure out a way to store key value pairs and then compare them to get the max out of it.

```
  * def keys = []
  * eval karate.forEach(response.lineItems, function(k){ keys.add(k) })
  * print keys
```

ust to be more clear on what I am trying here,

I am trying to hit the following endpoint:

```
http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/history.json?key={apikey}&q=London&dt=2020-03-03&end_dt=2020-03-03
```

The structure of the response has something like:

```
{
    "location": {
        "name": "London",
        "region": "City of London, Greater London",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "lat": 51.52,
        "lon": -0.11,
        "tz_id": "Europe/London",
        "localtime_epoch": 1583594426,
        "localtime": "2020-03-07 15:20"
    },
    "forecast": {
        "forecastday": [
            {
                "date": "2020-03-03",
                "date_epoch": 1583193600,
                "day": {
                    "maxtemp_c": 9,
                    "maxtemp_f": 48.2,
                    "mintemp_c": 4,
                    "mintemp_f": 39.2,
                     .....
                     .....
                }
           },
           {
                "date": "2020-03-04",
                "date_epoch": 1583366400,
                "day": {
                    "maxtemp_c": 7,
                    "maxtemp_f": 44.6,
                    "mintemp_c": 5.6,
                    "mintemp_f": 42.1,
                    .........
                    .........
                 }
            },
        and so on ...for 3 more days...
```

so

```
forecastday[0].date=2020-03-03
forecastday[0].day.maxtemp_c=9
```

Now I want to store forecastday[x].date and value forecast[x].day.maxtemp_c say as a string value pair like {2020-03-03 : 9, 2020-03-04 : 7, and so on}
And then be able to choose the maximum temperate date like for example on 2020-03-03 was the highest temparture of say 9degrees...so I choose 2020-03-03 as the parameter to be passed on to the next end point.

So my requirement is to parse the response, look at the date and the max temperature on that date and then choose the date with the highest temparature in the last 5 days or 15 days or 30 days(no of days going back is configurable in the java code)

Any help and recommendations would be really useful.